# Проблема с программой, связанная с пустым окном. PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Проблема заключается в том, что я хотел написать программу у которой нет оконного режима(то есть нет поверхностного интерфейса, кнопки закрыть и свернуть) и мне это удалось сделать, но это окно теперь нельзя перетащить. Я воспользовался этим кодом:

```
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
```

Comment: Если какой-то ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить его  как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

или так

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, ev):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)        
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor(195, 195, 255))
        painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(self.rect(), 10.0, 10.0)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):                                      # <<<-----
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):                                       # <<<-----
        delta = QtCore.QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
        self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А `Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground` специально добавили для рисования скругленного окна? :)

Comment: @gil9red  да, сделать прозрачный фон для нарисованных объектов

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно перекрыть методы-события:

- В [mousePressEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent) фиксируется клик кнопки мышки
- В [mouseReleaseEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent) отпускание кнопки мышки
- В [mouseMoveEvent](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) выполняется перемещение окна

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/2ce03859474058a5c9611adca030f4f8d8931d4c/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__mouse_manual_move__FramelessWindowHint.py#L11)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self._old_pos = None

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Закрыть окно", clicked=self.close))

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return

        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = Widget()
    w.resize(400, 400)
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Сергей, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)